# Long Vs. Int C/C++ - What's The Point?

Tags: c++, c, integer, long-integer

As I've learned recently, a `long` in C/C++ is the same length as an `int`.  To put it simply, why?  It seems almost pointless to even include the datatype in the language.  Does it have any uses specific to it that an `int` doesn't have?  I know we can declare a 64-bit `int` like so:

```
long long x = 0;
```

But why does the language choose to do it this way, rather than just making a `long` well...longer than an `int`?  Other languages such as C# do this, so why not C/C++?

Comment: The reaon we use types like u8, s16, s32, u64, etc.

Comment: "a long in C/C++ is the same length as an int." Not always. The C++ standard specifies that an `int` be the "natural" size for the processor, which may not always be as big as a `long`. The standard also guarantees that a `long` is at least as long as an `int`, so the fact that they are equal sizes are not always guaranteed.

Comment: Historical and architectural baggage.  Believe me, it can hurt making assumptions like you make about `int` and `long` always being the same size; I am currently fixing a ton of portability issues in one of our C++ static libraries as we transition to a 64-bit architecture

Comment: Practically speaking, `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)` only on 32-bit architectures or 64-bit Windows, where it comes as a shock to programmers who are used to `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void *)`.

Comment: IMO, the integers are `char`, `short`, `long`, and `long long`.  `int` is just a "typedef" for whichever is fastest on my system.

Comment: I still find all this "long" and "short" nonsense to be mostly pointless. It may be this long on this architecture and that long on that one and it may have yet another length on another architecture. Utterly unportable. IMO there should only be a single integer type (with signed and unsigned variations, of course), and if you need anything of a specific size then there should be types (as there are) which have a fixed, guaranteed size (i.e. uint8, uint16, etc.).

Comment: @antred Agreed. `long` does not mean `longer than int` (It means that it's at least the size of `int` and possibly longer - Usually not the case). However, C does guarantee that, at a minimum, `unsigned int` can hold at least `65,535`, while `signed long` is `2,147,483,647`. Though I'd argue you *should* know more about the architecture of where you're building, this at least guarantees that you'll always be able to hold up to `2,147,483,647` number  if you use `long`.

Comment: Just for kicks I'll throw this out there: on 8-bit Arduino microcontroller development boards at least (using Atmel's ATmega328 microcontroller, for example), `char` is 8-bits, `short` is 16-bits, `int` is 16-bits, and `long` is 32-bits. So in this case `short` and `int` are identical, while `long` truly is longer.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

When writing in C or C++, every datatype is architecture and compiler specific. On one system int is 32, but you can find ones where it is 16 or 64; it's not defined, so it's up to compiler.

As for `long` and `int`, it comes from times, where standard integer was 16bit, where `long` was 32 bit integer - and it indeed *was* longer than `int`.

Comment: So it's really just a legacy thing, then?

Comment: @MGZero: You're sort of right, but you didn't read the answer fully. There was a time in the long past when `int` and `short` were the same size on many platforms. If `int` were still 16 bits, then that would be a 'legacy' thing. `int` is basically meant to represent a very efficient size for integers on whatever platform you happen to be on.

Comment: +1 - also prob good to mention that this is why c99 defined the `uintNN_t` etc types to clear things up.

Comment: @Brian Roach: Which many C implementations have stupidly still not implemented.  Grr... *sigh*

Comment: @MGZero, **Not at all**, this continues to vary by platform, and there are _many_ platforms still define `int` and `long` of different size.

Comment: This is completely wrong on many platforms. As a common example, ``int`` is 16 bits on AVR microcontrollers, which are common teaching tools in university CS courses.

Comment: @MostAwesomeDude: what is wrong? I have written it's compiler- and architecture-specific. Is that wrong? From what I see in your comment, you actually agreed with me...

Comment: @Griwes, you imply that this is a thing of the *past*, when in fact, the present has plenty of platforms where `long` and `int` are different sizes, and the future shows no signs of not having such platforms. You don't describe the actual rules governing the sizes of types in C at all.

Comment: @Mike: As I read it, he explains the rationale for the current situation, a rationale which by necessity must be found in the past.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a legacy thing or only found in the past. It's a portability thing.. The C/C++ standards are defined with some minimum degree of portability in mind, and were written in such a way as to only provide minimalistic definitions in relation to each other. A long is not the same size as an int, it's only guaranteed to be *no smaller* than an int, but if the platform/compiler requires it to be larger, it is free to do so. On some platforms, int may be 16 bits and long is 32 bits. On others, they may both be 32 bits. On still others, 32 and 64 bits, respectively, and so on.

Comment: Implementations with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long` are very common. (I'm typing this comment on such a system.)

Answer (score 65):

The specific guarantees are as follows:

- `char` is at least 8 bits (1 byte by definition, however many bits it is)
- `short` is at least 16 bits
- `int` is at least 16 bits
- `long` is at least 32 bits
- `long long` (in versions of the language that support it) is at least 64 bits
- Each type in the above list is *at least* as wide as the previous type (but may well be the same).

Thus it makes sense to use `long` if you need a type that's at least 32 bits, `int` if you need a type that's reasonably fast and at least 16 bits.

Actually, at least in C, these lower bounds are expressed in terms of *ranges*, not sizes.  For example, the language requires that `INT_MIN <= -32767`, and `INT_MAX >= +32767`.  The 16-bit requirements follows from this and from the requirement that integers are represented in binary.

C99 adds `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>`, which define types such as `uint32_t`, `int_least32_t`, and `int_fast16_t`; these are typedefs, usually defined as aliases for the predefined types.

(There isn't *necessarily* a direct relationship between size and range.  An implementation could make `int` 32 bits, but with a range of only, say, `-2**23 .. +2^23-1`, with the other 8 bits (called *padding bits*) not contributing to the value.  It's theoretically possible (but practically highly unlikely) that `int` could be larger than `long`, as long as `long` has at least as wide a *range* as `int`.  In practice, few modern systems use padding bits, or even representations other than 2's-complement, but the standard still permits such oddities.  You're more likely to encounter exotic features in embedded systems.)

Comment: Then there is a problem. Because almost everyone assumes that int will store 32 bit number. So they usually put million into the int variable. Nowadays everyone assumes it's 32bits I think. If we are going to be politically correct, everyone should start to use long as their default data type.

Comment: @off99555 There is no "default data type". You can safely assume that `int` is at least 32 bits if you're on an implementation that makes that guarantee; all POSIX-conforming systems do so. If you make that assumption, your code won't be portable to systems with 16-bit `int`. That may or may not be a good tradeoff. (And being "politically correct" is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 24):

long is not the same length as an int. According to the specification, long is at least as large as int. For example, on Linux x86_64 with GCC, sizeof(long) = 8, and sizeof(int) = 4.

Answer (score 15):

`long` is not the same size as `int`, it is *at least* the same size as `int`. To quote the C++03 standard (3.9.1-2):

> There are four signed integer types: “signed char”, “short int”,
>   “int”, and “long int.” In this list, each type provides at least as
>   much storage as those preceding it in the list. Plain ints have the
>   natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution
>   environment); the other signed integer types are provided to meet special needs.

My interpretation of this is "just use `int`, but if for some reason that doesn't fit your needs and you are lucky to find another integral type that's better suited, be our guest and use that one instead". One way that `long` might be better is if you 're on an architecture where it is... longer.

Comment: "One way that long might be better is if you 're on an architecture where it is... longer." Not really. `long` might be better if you write portable code and you need integer of at least 32-bits. `long` is guaranteed to be not less than 32-bits by C standard. `int` is not guaranteed (it may be 16-bits).

Comment: @SergeDundich: Very true. No excuses for not addressing the question in C for me.

Answer (score 12):

looking for something completely unrelated and stumbled across this and needed to answer.  Yeah, this is old, so for people who surf on in later...

Frankly, I think all the answers on here are incomplete.

The size of a long is the size of the number of bits your processor can operate on at one time.  It's also called a "word".  A "half-word" is a short.  A "doubleword" is a long long and is twice as large as a long (and originally was only implemented by vendors and not standard), and even bigger than a long long is a "quadword" which is twice the size of a long long but it had no formal name (and not really standard).

Now, where does the int come in?  In part registers on your processor, and in part your OS.  Your registers define the native sizes the CPU handles which in turn define the size of things like the short and long.  Processors are also designed with a data size that is the most efficient size for it to operate on.  That should be an int.

On todays 64bit machines you'd assume, since a long is a word and a word on a 64bit machine is 64bits, that a long would be 64bits and an int whatever the processor is designed to handle, but it might not be.  Why?  Your OS has chosen a data model and defined these data sizes for you (pretty much by how it's built).  Ultimately, if you're on Windows (and using Win64) it's 32bits for both a long and int.  Solaris and Linux use different definitions (the long is 64bits).  These definitions are called things like ILP64, LP64, and LLP64.  Windows uses LLP64 and Solaris and Linux use LP64:

```
Model      ILP64   LP64   LLP64
int        64      32     32
long       64      64     32
pointer    64      64     64
long long  64      64     64
```

Where, e.g., ILP means int-long-pointer, and LLP means long-long-pointer

To get around this most compilers seem to support setting the size of an integer directly with types like int32 or int64.

Comment: "*The size of a long is the size of the number of bits your processor can operate on at one time.*" -- The standard doesn't say or imply that, and it's not always true. On a system with 16-bit words that needs multiple instructions to operate on a 32-bit quantity, `long` is still required to be at least 32 bits. There is no requirement that `short` is half the width of `long`, or that `long long` is twice the width of `long` -- and neither is true on the system I'm using (16-bit `short`, 64-bit `long`, 64-bit `long long`).

Comment: Finally, *all* conforming C and C++ compilers define `int32_t` and `int64_t` in `<stdint.h>` (introduced in C in 1999 and later adopted by C++). That's assuming the implementation has types that support the requirements; not all do.

Comment: Since you didn't tag me in your comment, I didn't see it until just now. I did in fact read the entire answer. What about my comments makes you think I didn't?

Comment: this is a bad answer. it is confidently inaccurate, and even internally contradictory