# Size of long vs int on x64 platform

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Having read [Difference between long and int data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900230/difference-in-long-vs-int-data-types-in-c) and [Long Vs. Int C/C++ - What's The Point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456902/long-vs-int-c-c-whats-the-point)

i'm trying to generate outputs of sizeof(int) and sizeof(long) by creating a 32 bit exe and a 64 bit exe.

I'm using visual studio 2010 on Windows 7 ultimate x64 SP1 and have selected x64 in the configuration manager. My pre-processor is also set to WIN64. However, i still get the sizeof(int) and sizeof(long) as 4 bytes, no matter whether i create a 32 bit exe or a 64 one.

Is there some other compiler flag that i need to set to generate a x64 exe (I cannot see the generated exe in x64/Debug folder of my project)

Comment: The size of a long is unrelated to the processor capability.  In Visual c++, a long is 4 bytes.

Comment: Agner's [Calling Conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) contains a table of the sizes of different types in different platforms. For windows `long` is 4 bytes as `int`, both in 32 and 64bit architectures

Comment: I think page 22 explains everything fine. http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329777/is-long-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-32-bits

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: For _Visual Studio_ `long` is 4 bytes.  I believe G++ on Windows uses an 8 byte `long` type.

Comment: Your expectation of what should happen is quite reasonable, and is what would happen in the ILP64 model. Visual C++ compilers don't use that model though. Read [**this**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).

Comment: I'm amused that the first link in this question says "both `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)` return 4" and "most compilers for these platforms use a 32 bit int which has the same size and representation as a long."  Did he not read the pages he linked to?  Second link says "a long in C/C++ is the same length as an int."

Comment: Microsoft explicitly chose an LLP64 model. The [Raymond Chen blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/31/363790.aspx) hints as to the why. Any conforming compiler on the platform really has to keep to this model, otherwise they will produce non-working code. Only pointers were extended to 64bit, and the `long long` data type is used for 64bit integer representations.

Comment: There are two unrelated questions here. One is about `sizeof(int)` and the other is about setting compiler flags. The first one is more or less answered. As for the second one, you need to open the [configuration manager](http://siddhantahuja.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/new-configuration-manager.png), make sure you have an x64 configuration, set your project for that configuration to use the x64 platform, and off you go.

Comment: @Layne: That explains the requirements of the C standard; the question is about a specific implementation.