# overflow when change from string to int in C

Tags: c, string, int

In the C programming language, a string such as `"2147483649"` overflows as an int since the largest unsigned int is `2147483647`. When I want to convert strings of integers to `int`s, how do I go about checking for these overflow cases?

I can't just check if it is `>=-(2^32-1)` and `<= (2^32-1)` since the process of converting this string to an `int` (eg `atoi()`) already changes this value. Is there an easy way instead of checking the number of digits of the string before converting and also each digit at a time to make sure it's within the range of `int`s?

Comment: Why use `atoi()`? Use `strtol()` / `strtoll()` for better.

Comment: Use `strtol`, `atoi()` has no error checking. Check limits with `LONG_MAX` and `LONG_MIN` from `limits.h`

Comment: May be this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456902/long-vs-int-c-c-whats-the-point

Comment: If you need convert larger values how about using `atoll` (if you can use C99)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `atoi()` on a value that cannot be represented as an integer invokes undefined behaviour. I.e. you should not use `atoi()`.

Instead you can use `strtol()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

long val = strtol("2147483649", 0, 10);
if (val == LONG_MIN && errno == ERANGE) {
    …underflow…
} else if (val == LONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE) {
    …overflow…
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can convert the resulting integer back to string and compare it to the source string. Although it doesn't look elegant to me. :-)

Comment: I was about to say the same thing.

Comment: That still invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtol()`.  It gives you a `long` so if on your platform that's larger than an `int` you can check that for overflow.  And if the number in the string doesn't even fit in a `long`, the function will return a special value `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` and set `errno`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're implementing your own `atoi` function, you can check for overflow as you accumulate the result:

```
int value = 0;
for-each digit-character in string
    int newValue = value + ( 10 * place * digit-character )
    if newValue < value then die("overflow detected")
    value = newValue
next
```

Comment: One problem you've got there. I know because I wrote the same thing and found the bug, ahah. Try it with 6147483648 for example. On the second last iteration, when you multiply 614748364 by 10, it overflows twice and it still ends up at x mod 2^31 = 1852516352, larger than the previous iteration.