# What is the difference between long and long int in c?

Tags: c, integer, long-integer

I know that an **integer** has a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647 and a **long** has the range of -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 but what range does a **long int** have?

Comment: `long` and `long int` are the same thing. The `int` is optional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Long Vs. Int C/C++ - What's The Point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456902/long-vs-int-c-c-whats-the-point)

Comment: `int` can be omitted when any of `signed`, `unsigned`, `long` or `short` are used. `long` and `long int` mean the exact same thing.

Comment: *"I know that `long` has the range of -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807"*. Only when the `long` is 64-bits. It can be 32 bits.

Comment: `integer has a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647 and a long has the range of -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807` the C and C++ standards don't specify any specific size for any built-in types. The only requirement is that `int` has at least 16 bits and `long` has at least 32 bits: [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/995714)

Comment: `long`, `long int`, `signed long` and `signed long int` all refer to the same type. But you're wrong about the range of both `int` and `long`. See [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) Used the fixed-width integer types mentioned therein if you want to guarantee certain ranges.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that an integer has a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647

Then you know wrong. The standard only says minimum values and those are much lower than those (-32767, 32767).

C language has special defines for the minimum and maximum integer values. For example for the `int` type: `INT_MIN` & `INT_MAX`. They are defined in the `limits.h` header file.

You can also check how long (in `char`) your type is by using `sizeof` operator. If you want to know haw many `bits` it has: `sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT`

> What is the difference between long and long int in c?

There us no difference as `int` can be omitted. Same is with `unsigned` (`unsigned int`), `short` (`short int`) and `long long` (`long long int`).

Comment: the limit for `int` is `[-32767, 32767]`, not (-32768, 32767) because C and older C++ allows one's complement and sign-magnitude formats

Comment: @phuclv indeed.